# Why does Java writeBytes method send only one byte in first TCP packet and write method does not?

Tags: java, tcp, byte, packet

I have developing a simple client in java (I use a Windows 7 machine) to communicate with a server. The problem was that the server never understood my request. So I have analysed the communication with Wireshark and have noticed that only one byte is send in a first TCP packet, and 40ms after the remaining bytes are send in a other packet.

In fact, we communicate with binary frames, so all the frames must begin with the total length of the frame on 2 bytes. So it is normal that the server will never understand me. All my frames never exceed 10 bytes, so it's a insignificant amount of data. I know that TCP packets can be segmented, but for me it has no sense to segment a tiny frame after only one byte.

After unsuccessful hours of research, I tried casually to send bytes in a other way using write method instead of writeBytes method. Now I send all the data in only one TCP packet and the communication works fine, but I have never find the explanation. If someone knows, I will be happy to learn it.

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.2.1.1", 1003), 1000);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        // Hexadecimal frame to send to server
        String hexFrame = "0004FF9D3175";

        // Build bytes frame
        String bytesFrame = "";
        for (int i=0; i<hexFrame.length()/2; i++) {
            bytesFrame += (char) Integer.parseInt(hexFrame.substring(i*2, (i+1)*2), 16);
        }

        // This generates 2 TCP packets
        // outToServer.writeBytes(bytesFrame);
        // This generates only 1 TCP packet
        outToServer.write(bytesFrame.getBytes());

        // Read answer from server
        hexFrame = "";
        short frame_length = inFromServer.readShort();
        for (int i=0; i<frame_length; i++) {
            hexFrame += String.format("%2s", Integer.toHexString(inFromServer.readUnsignedByte())).replace(" ", "0");
        }

        System.out.println("Receive : " + hexFrame);

        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Java nor TCP makes any guarantees about this. TCP can segment the data any way it likes, and you have no business relying on any two bytes being delivered consecutively. The problem here is really at the reading end, that makes incorrect assumptions.

> In fact, we communicate with binary frames

In fact you are communicating over a byte-stream protocol. No frames, no message boundaries, nothing.

However, if you want a little more control over this you should use a `BufferedOutputStream` between the `DataOutputStream` and the socket output stream, and similarly a `BufferedInputStream` at the receiving end. Flush the stream when you want the data to be sent, typically just before the next read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, using buffered stream and flush it before next read makes the code stronger, so I have applied those modifications. But out of curiosity, I have tried to send ascii frame with  termination character, "Hello\n" for example and write a basic server in java. writeBytes method ALWAYS send the first byte ("H") in a separate TCP packet whereas write method NEVER does. I don't care if packets are segmented and are re-assembled on the server in order to see only one frame. But that not the case, my actual server see two separated frame with writeBytes method.

Comment: It does that because the underlying stream isn't buffered. `writeBytes()` actually writes one byte at a time out of the string. TCP will send the first byte immediately, but then enter Nagle mode and start buffering while there is unacknowledged data in flight. If you add the `BufferedOutputStream` and flush as indicated it won't happen. `writeBytes()` is possibly the wrong API to use for another reason: it just throws the high byte of each `char` away, so it restricts the character sets you can use.

Comment: Okay ! That you for your explainations !